# How to reset nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a nested ng-repeat with a filter to group by.

I have created this 
    [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mun2a20a/2/).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data =[
    {subject: 'English',module: 'Literature', score: 95}, 
    {subject: 'Maths',module: 'Calculus', score: 90}
   ];

   $scope.dropScore = function() {
      if ($scope.data[0].score > 0) {
       $scope.data[0].score -= 8;
      }
   }

   $scope.origData = angular.copy($scope.data)

   $scope.reset = function () {
     $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.origData);
   };
}])

.filter('groupBy', function() {
  return _.memoize(function(items, field) {
      return _.groupBy(items, field);
  }
 );
});
```

When you press the button hit score the score of English drops but clicking reset will reset the $scope.data value but not show the updated data on the screen.

Can someone help with this

Comment: Added an answer, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pb79h20q/)

Just use this `reset` method:

```
$scope.reset = function () {   
      $scope.data[0].score = angular.copy($scope.origData[0].score);      
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` to refresh your scope :

```
$scope.dropScore = function() {
   if ($scope.data[0].score > 0) {
    $scope.data[0].score -= 8;
    $scope.$apply();
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zewaeqpx/

Comment: If I press hit score once then click reset I am still see English - 87 rather than English - 95

Comment: Actually your groupBy is somehow weird : http://jsfiddle.net/zewaeqpx/2/ and you don't need $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ng-repeat=(subject, value) in data | groupBy: 'subject'`, you are creating another array for ng-repeat to use. So either you would need to assign each parameter within or not use the filter in the ng-repeat.

**Option 1:**
If you want to keep how you are using the ng-repeat, you could to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mwxe6nfb/):

```
$scope.reset = function () {
    _.forEach($scope.data, function(subject, idx){
        subject.score = $scope.origData[idx].score;
    });
};
```

**Option 2:**
or you could simplify your ng-repeat so that it works like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ut26m4fa/) where the template becomes:

```
<li ng-repeat="subject in data">
  <span ng-bind="subject.subject"></span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-bind="subject.module + ' - ' + subject.score">
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

You should use ng-bind because in some browsers, when the data attribute is not loaded, it will flash {{}} for a split second before it loads.